# Which is correct: “carved in stone” or “carved into stone”?

Tags: differences

I realize the first is more of a phrase, but which is grammatically correct? Does it depend on the object of the sentence (e.g. stone vs wall)?

Would I say: “He carved his name in rock” or “He carved his name into rock”? If they’re both the correct, when would you use one over the other?

Comment: They are both perfectly grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

**carve (something) in stone** the idiom  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/carve+in+stone)

> To make something permanent and incapable of being changed, typically
>   a plan or idea. We might get brunch next weekend, but we haven't
>   carved anything in stone yet.

The other:

> Carved into or on a tree, wall, a vase etc.... (literal)

Both are correct but with different meanings.

Comment: I realized that my question was poorly worded. I edited my post to clarify

Comment: Also "carved in stone" is used to describe a free-standing sculpture rather than an inscription or bas-relief. For example "The war memorial consists of the figure of a soldier, carved in stone, standing on a plinth" as opposed to "The names of the fallen are carved into the stone of the plinth".